# Remove All Bluetooth Devices / Previous Connections / Forget Everything (MacOS 13.4)

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

Some context: new MacBook user trying to use a custom wireless split keyboard on my MacBook Pro 2021, macOS 13.4.

I got the keyboard to connect at some point, but then I flashed a new firmware on it, and it seems not to work anymore. On my other laptop (Ubuntu 20.04), I see two Bluetooth devices with the same name (both being this keyboard). One of them is working, and one of them is not. I've faced similar issues with multi profile keyboards and headsets that I used to connect to two operating systems running on the same laptop (Windows and Linux). But this is fairly easy to do in Ubuntu, I just open Bluez, I can see the addresses of the devices and just remove/forget them from there.

What I suspect is happening is that the MacBook sees only the one that's not working. I'm not sure if it makes any sense.

My question is: Is there any way to completely purge, wipe, or remove from existence, all the Bluetooth devices that this MacBook was ever aware of? I've tried the methods mentioned on the first 20 results from Google and it didn't work.

Comment: Try to include some more detail. What do you mean by "all the Bluetooth devices that this Macbook was ever aware of"? Doesn't forgetting the device work for you / isn't it sufficient? When you talk about the "first 20 results from Google", what have you searched to get those results? What were they? Why didn't they work?